# Addressing mechanisms in neural turing machine

Tags: neural-network, lstm, rnn

In a Neural Turing Machine,why wasn't an absolute random access mechanism used?We are reading and writing based on the weighting emitted by the read/write head and this weighting is being generated by addressing mechanisms:content based addressing and location based addressing.Can anyone explain the need for generating these weightings with these mechanisms.